# Как изменить значения в базе данных при изменении значений в гриде?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как изменить значения в базе данных при изменении значений в гриде? Нигде не могу найти ответ. Хочу, чтоб при изменении, удалении, добавлении значений в грид, всё это передавалось в базу. У меня, всё кэшируется в датасете. Способы, которые работают в `winForms`, тут не работают. При перезапуске я вижу всё то же, что и было раньше в гриде, без изменений, которые вносил.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
 /// </summary>
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
 DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
 SqlDataAdapter da;
 public MainWindow()
 {
 InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 SqlConnection Connection = CreateConnection();
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
 da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Students", Connection);
 // Объект CommandBuilder автоматически выполняет команды UPDATE и INSERT
 SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

 // Объект DataTable отслеживает и сохраняет в памяти изменения
 //DataTable dt = new DataTable();

 // Теперь заполняем объект DataTable данными
 da.Fill(dataset);

 // Привязываем элемент управления DataGridView к объекту DataTable
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;

 }
 SqlConnection CreateConnection()
 {
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
 connection.ConnectionString = @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=2med;Data Source=ROMAN-ПК\ROMAN";
 try
 {
 connection.Open();
 MessageBox.Show("ok");
 }
 catch
 {
 MessageBox.Show("Ошибка соединения с базой данных");
 }

 return connection;
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
 da.Update((dataset.Tables[0]));

 }

 }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4" >
 <Grid >
 <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="93,16,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
 <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,20,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="110,95,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328" >

 </DataGrid>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Нашёл ответ
добавляю

this.allstudents = new DataTable("Allstudents");
     this.StudentsAdapter.Fill(this.allstudents);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(this.StudentsAdapter);//нужна была именно эта строка, тогда будет сохраняться после при вызове следующего кода:


при сохранении(привязываем это к кнопке или событию после модификации грида)
this.StudentsAdapter.Update(Allstudents); //

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, дело в том что Visual Studio при каждом запуске копирует базу в папку debug (или release). Поэтому при каждом запуске она как бы новая. Это можно настроить через свойство “Copy to Output Directory” (правая кнопка мыши по файлу базы данных). По умолчанию оно равно “Copy always”, то есть всегда копировать. Поставьте "Do not copy" (точно не помню).
[Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/41631/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%B4)

Comment: А можно по побробней? я не нашёл там “Copy to Output Directory”.