# Как правильно записать данные в таблицу БД?

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, c#

Здравствуйте! Как правильно вставить данные в таблицу БД? На данном этапе я использую это:

```
OleDbCommand command = наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + skladDataSet1.Наименование_товаров.TableName + "] (Группа, Наименование товара) VALUES (@"+comboBox1.Text +",@"+textBox1.Text+")";
                    наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Получается что:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Наименование товаров] (Группа, Наименование товара) VALUES (@Молочные,@Творог)"
```

Но вылезает ошибка синтаксиса `INSERT INTO`. В чем проблема? Далее попробовал так:

```
наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Insert(comboBox1.Text, textBox1.Text);
dataGridView4.DataSource = наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.GetData();
```

Данные вставляются и отображаются, но не сохраняются. Что сделать, чтобы они сохранялись?

UPD:

Блин, я все равно ничего не пойму... делаю так..

```
OleDbCommand command = наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [" + skladDataSet1.Наименование_товаров.TableName + "] ([Группа], [Наименование товара]) VALUES ('"+comboBox1.Text +"','"+textBox1.Text+"')";
                наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                skladDataSet1.Наименование_товаров.AcceptChanges();
                наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Update(skladDataSet1);
                skladDataSet1.AcceptChanges();
                наименование_товаровTableAdapter1.Connection.Close();
```

Данные вставляются, но если сразу же после закрытия запустить программу, то она отобразит новые данные, но если через время, то ничего нету... В чем дело?..
Спасибо.

Comment: Может нужно вызвать метод AcceptChanges() ?

Comment: Да, точно) Спасибо) Но как быть с синтаксисом INSERT INTO? В некоторых моментах он мне просто необходим)

Comment: возможно дело в пробеле в названии поля? или в лишних "собачках"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фууух, наконец-то))

Надо просто в Обозревателе решений у объекта base.mdb в свойстве "Копировать в выходной путь" поставить "Не копировать", а БД скопировать в папку debug/bin т.к. сама программа работает с базой, которая находится в папке вместе с файлом *.exe, но если свойство "копировать" стоит, то она каждый раз при запуске затирает измененную базу, на базу указанную в строке подключения.